# Getting element in table wihout ID

Tags: java, selenium

I'm trying to access the input type element on a webpage but Selenium can't find the element.

I've already tried it with: `xpath=//input[@name='name']`

```html
<frameset rows="100%,*" border="0" frameborder="0">
<frame src="/test/loginEntry" scrolling="AUTO" name="bannerframe" noresize="">
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body onmousedown="mouseDownEventOcurred(); onkeypress="keyPressedEventOccured();">
  <form action ="https://website.com/login" name="login" method="POST">
    <table style="width: 100%; margin: 0 auto;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
   <tbody>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr>
           <td colspan="2">
              <table>
              <tbody>
              <tr>
              <td>Name:</td>
              <td>
               <input type="text" size="20" maxlength="20" name="name" style="text-align:left">
              </td>
              <td></td>
           </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
    </frame>
```

I need the input **type"text"** element and I get a `NoSuchElementException`. I've tried it with **CSS Selector** and **Webdriver** wait as well. I think it might be becuase of the table but I don't know how to access the

Comment: Provide more info like html source or something?

Comment: what is the exception you are getting ? Why are using xpath when name attribute is given ?

Comment: This is the exception I'm getting: Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Cannot locate an element using By.xpath: //input[@name='name']

Comment: Can you check for iframe  ? Go little bit up in DOM and check for <iframe>, <frame>, <frameset>, tag.

Comment: There are no iframes, just <frame src="test/loginEntry" scrolling="AUTO">

Comment: Can you share more of the HTML?

Comment: yeah, <frame> tag is there, you need to switch to it before accessing the elements which are inside the frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input element is inside the frame, you will have to switch the focus of webdriver to frame first, then you can access the input tag.

Code for switching to frame:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//frame[contains(@src,'loginEntry')]")));
```

Just make sure that `//frame[contains(@src,'loginEntry')]` xpath should be unique.

Answer (score 1):

This may be the problem of Wait. You need to wait for that component.Try the code below:

```
WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@name='name']")));
```